# How many subsets of a set $S$ of consecutive integers total to exactly $M$?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

I encountered this as a subproblem of a MATHCOUNTS Handbook question. (Not a competition question, so it's allowed to discuss it.) In that question, the set was $\{2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$, and $M$ was $10$. I solved it via exhaustive search, but I was wondering if there was a better way. Ideally, it should be something that doesn't use any advanced math, since it should be explainable to a middle-schooler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $10 \notin \{2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$, we need at least two elements of the set.

If we use two elements, their average must be 
$$\frac{10}{2} = 5$$
Since a two-element subset consists of two different numbers, the only two-element subset we can use is $\{4, 6\}$.

If we use three elements, one of them must be $2$ since the smallest sum we can obtain without using $2$ is $3 + 4 + 5 = 12 > 10$.  We must also use $3$ since the smallest sum we can obtain without using both $2$ and $3$ is $2 + 4 + 5 = 11 > 10$.  Hence, the only such subset is $\{2, 3, 5\}$.

We cannot use four or more numbers since the smallest sum we can obtain with at least four elements of the set is $2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 14 > 10$.